# How could i put following-sibling elements count into variable, with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

For example, I've got structure like that:

```html
<div>
  <br />
  <div class='myClass'>123</div>  <- WebElement
  <br />
  <br />  
</div>
<br />
```

I've got WebElement object("//div[@class='myClass']") and I want to put result of following xpath into variable :

```
count(./following-sibling::br)
```

Expected result: 2.

How could i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the count value of xpath to variable. But you can use it with find Elements and compare the count in another way as given below.

```
WebElement myClass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='myClass']"));

List<WebElement> followingSiblings = myClass.findElements(By.xpath("./following-siblings::br");

int count = follwoingSiblings.size();

Assert.assertEquals(count, 2);
```